# Serialize a c++ virtual class without boost?

Tags: c++, serialization

I want to dump some data into files, then load it back. i do care the performance.

I don't want to use `boost serialization`. I want to serialize and load it back by myself.

if the struct is `POD`, i think this will be quite easy, but there is some problems if my data class has virtual function, like this:

```
// base.h
#include <string>
class Base {
 public:
  virtual std::string show_string() = 0;
  int b;
};

class A : public Base {
 public:
  std::string show_string() override { return "this is A"; }  // here is the problem, virtual pointer
  int a;
};
```

there is a data producer, dump the data into file, like this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include "./base.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
  std::fstream f;
  f.open("a.bin", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    A a;
    a.a = i;
    a.b = i - 1;
    f.write((char*)&a, sizeof(a));
  }
  f.close();
}
```

then i need to load it back, my code looks like:

```
#include "./base.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  std::fstream f;
  f.open("a.bin", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
  char buff[65536];
  f.read(buff, sizeof(buff));
  A* a = (A*)buff;
  cout << a->show_string() << endl;
  f.close();
}
```

this will crashed, i think the problem is the virtual pointer.

for virtual pointer, i think i need a correct serialize method.

could you help on this? how can i make this work?

Comment: You open an input stream and then *write* to it? Shouldn't you be *reading* from it instead? You also save binary data, which means you should really open the files in *binary* mode.

Comment: And as you mention, you just save the raw data, which means the virtual function table and its pointers will be save. These pointers, like any other pointers, can't be serialized as is. You need to come up with a way to write and read only the actual data.

Comment: And if you don't want to use Boost, there are other libraries and frameworks that handle or include serialization. Or just do the sensible thing, and don't save data in binary form: Use text-files and the normal stream output and input operator `<<` and `>>`. Any possible performance hits will most likely be negligible. And you really need to measure and profile and only optimize if it's a top-two or three bottleneck in your program, or if you have specific and explicit requirements.

Comment: that can work, but i think binary format is the most effective way, i do care the speed, i think i just need to think a way to make virtual function works, which is a little part of these libraries. if i can learn that part, it will be great

Comment: Personally, I'd recommend using [nlohmann::json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) for serialisation. Write a helper method e.g. `toJson()` that converts all the data you require, them `json.dump()`. If you're looking for maximum file savings, you could always `memcpy` it and dump it that way.

Comment: i thinks this part is the most sensitive part in my project, because i need to handle billions times for one run, so i want to make it as simple as i can

Comment: @SimonC thanks Simon, I considered json already, but the time cost will be 50 times of binary format.

Comment: Now you have turned this into an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What is the *actual* problem you need to solve? Why do you need "billions times" to save and load files? Perhaps there are other solutions available? Please ask about your original and underlying problem directly instead.

Comment: Also check the usual recommendations for this: protocol buffers and flatbuffers.

Comment: You already have a class hierarchy, so write your own virtual serialization methods for reading and writing. Build serialization helper methods into the base class to make it easy. I would write a method that serializes bytes along with a size, and then use function templates to wrap that for anything I pass it. Non-POD types can be specializations of this. If most of your actual data is entirely POD, consider even storing that data in a struct inside these classes and save/load it in one hit.

Comment: If file size is important, consider something like [CBOR](https://cbor.io/)

Comment: @nick I feel you're missing out on the fact that you can serialise to BSON as well. Similar in size to protobuf, but with less fiddling around. I use both in production environments. When the files are needed locally only, but size is an issue, I'll use compressed BSON. Easy enough to detect when uncompressing

Comment: @paddy, in my understanding, the data will be stored, but when i call the virtual function from the loaded-back object, it will crash, because the loaded-back class virtual pointer is invalid. so the problem is how to get back the virtual pointer

Comment: there is no "hidden state". Just only need a constructor that can construct an `A` given `a` and `b`. You need not mess around with the virtual pointer, you merely must encode the type of the object, such that the other end can interpret it accordingly and use the data (`a` and `b`) to construct an `A` (by calling a cosntructor)

Comment: serialization is about not storing the raw bytes, but about storing the data in a format that the other end can interpret it. You seem to misunderstand that serialization is about dumping the raw bytes. Actually I do not understand the approach, because the other end needs to know what type of object it receives in some way anyhow

Comment: You need a class factory or some kind of other knowledge of the file structure which you construct as required with the correct types. You cannot just blit your binary data in the way you've shown.

Comment: `f.write((char*)&a, sizeof(a));` This is invitation for Undefined Behavior.